# Loading multiple images in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with displaying images in canvas. I don't get it why it's rendering only one image (background in this case). Here is my code:

```
    // ... Some code here

    this.createBackground( canvas, config );
    this.createPlayer( canvas, config );

  }

  createBackground( element, config ) {
    const canvas = element;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

    const bg = new Image();
    bg.src = "./img/" + config.bg;

    bg.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage( bg, 0, 0, config.width, config.height );
    }

    return bg;
  }

  createPlayer ( element, config ) {
    const canvas = element;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

    const player = new Image();
    player.src = "./img/" + config.character + "/Run1.png";

    player.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage( player, 70, 310, player.width/3, player.height/3 );
    }

    return player;
  }
```

Why my player doesn't appear in canvas after bg method?

Comment: Your background is probably bigger, therefore usually loads a bit longer and gets drawn last, covering the rest.

Comment: I thought about it, so it could be true. My bg is about 125kb and player is around 45kb.

Comment: Your way of drawing images whenever they are finished loading is atypical and leads to said issues. Draw images in a set order, making sure all are loaded beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you have media that is dependent on other media, load all the media at the start and wait till all have loaded before you start using them.

For example the following will load an array of images, using an array of urls to create and start the load. A counter counts each image as it is loaded and when the load count is equal to the number of images the function `allLoaded` is called.

```
const imageURL = ["foreground.jpg","background.jpg"]; // list of image URLs
const images = []; /// array to hold images.
var imageCount = 0; // number of loaded images;

// function called once all images have loaded.
function allLoaded(){
    // all images have loaded and can be rendered
    ctx.drawImage(images[1],0,0); // draw background
    ctx.drawImage(images[0],0,0); // draw foreground
}

// iterate each image URL, create, load, and add it to the images array
imageURL.forEach(src => {  // for each image url
     const image = new Image();
     image.src = src;
     image.onload = ()=>{ 
         imageCount += 1;
         if(imageCount === imageURL.length){ // have all loaded????
             allLoaded(); // call function to start rendering
         }
     }
     images.push(image); // add loading image to images array

});
// the image onload event will not be called until all current execution is
// complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure about contex globalCompositeOperation, try to set it to :

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
```

and also make sure about the canvas width and height, they should be greater than your player offset, like :

```
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
```